# When creating a WCF project in VS2010, I get "Error : WcfProject.csproj cannot be opened. The project type is not supported by this installation"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, visualsvn

hey there. So, we have a VS2010 project and the VisualSVN server on one machine. We added a new machine with the client visual svn and the projected loaded in. except for the WCF service. i'm getting a...

" error : the project file c:/..../wcfProject.csproj cannot be opened.

The project type is not supported by this installation."

i've checked the directory, the files and file structure are there and the same as the main development machine. any tips/solutions?

thanks
David K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things this could be so I can't give you one specific answer.  However, here are a few things to try on your machine that is throwing the error:

First, verify which version of Visual Studio is set as the default for opening csproj files.  It could be that you installed SQL or something else that uses an older version of Visual Studio.  Sometimes that can give an error.  Even if the default is the Visual Studio version selector I've seen it throw an error.  Open up the correct version of Visual Studio (through the Programs menu) and then inside Visual Studio try to open the package.  If that works, you know the issue is with which version is opening the file.

If that doesn't work, you could try resetting the Visual Studio settings.  From the run menu type `devenv /setup`  This should reset the Visual Studio environment and hopefully it will fix the issue.  If this does not work, try running `devenv /ResetSkipPkgs` from the Run menu.  This will try to load any packages that Visual Studio previously skipped.

If these steps don't work, let us know. Give us any further error messages that come up after attempting these steps.

Comment: Both the main and secondary machines are both running VS2010. Visualsvn was installed on the vs2010 and the project imported from there. The 'devenv /setup' didn't appear to do anything. When i tried the 'devenv /ResetSkipPkgs' it started up VS2005, but won't open the file from a newer version of VS.  When i try to build the project, in vs2010, i get errors on the crystal reports pages,  "'project.Crystal1.NewGenerator':no suitable method found to override"

Comment: @dave k - it sounds like your error has now changed.  This latest error suggests a problem with the Crystal Reports file after you moved it.  Here is a link that may help:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/6020cbe3-0e76-45a9-8198-84a16a592b1d/  It seems there may be a different version of Crystal Reports on the offending machine compared to your development machine.

Comment: The crystal reports was the problem! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem with some WCF solution which I [downloaded from a blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/andresv/archive/2011/09/01/dynamic-runtime-generation-of-a-wcf-service-contract.aspx).

The solutions of running deveng with the switches did not resolve my issues. After some more searching it turned out that the following clue in the answer of Ralph Willgoss lead to the solution of my problem:

> I resolved it by installing the Visual Web Developer.

I also had to (manually) install the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) to (automatically) download the last requirements for the project to properly load.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when trying to create a new project of the following types:

- WCF Service Application
- WCF Work Flow Service Application
- Syndication Service Library

I was using Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit, with no other versions of Visual Studio installed.

I also had tried many other options, such as:

- devenv /resetsettings
- devenv /resetskippkgs
- ensuring I had C++ option of VS2010 installed
- VS2010 Service Pack 1

I resolved it by installing the Visual Web Developer.